# Unable to integrate SignalR library in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, signalr.client

**I am getting the following exception when i try i run my project with signalR dependency:**

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)","position":{},"original":"com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"...while parsing microsoft/aspnet/signalr/client/Action.class","position":{},"original":"...while parsing microsoft/aspnet/signalr/client/Action.class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"1 error; aborting","position":{},"original":"1 error; aborting"}
```

**I have included the following commands in my app gradle file:**

**compile(name:'signalr-client-sdk-android-debug', ext:'aar')**
**compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')**

**Both the files are in the libs folder of my app directory.**

**What could be the issue???**

Comment: Issue was conflict in the java version I had in my system(1.8) and the one used to compile android.jar(1.7). Hence, i installed 1.7 in my system.

Answer (score 1):

download zip from [this](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client) link, extract it then import **signalr-client-sdk** and **signalr-client-sdk-android** in your project as module.

add `compile project(':signalr-client-sdk-android')`in your build.gradle.

sync your gradle, then run.. it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try to download all needed libraries from the following link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8POMankZlWcNGZ1Zm9td3pDNVk

After that, you should be able to compile all the .jar files from your app module biuld.gradle file.

```
compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
```

Now, you are able to use all the SignalR function in your android project.